# Vector subspace and linear application proof

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing

I would like to know if my proof is correct and, moreover, if it is well written.

> Let $E$ and $F$ be vector subspaces and $f: E \to F$ an application. Proof that, if $U$ is a vector subspace of $E$ and $f$ is a linear application, then $f(U)$ is a vector subspace of $F$.

Let $U = \langle u_1, \dots, u_n \rangle \subseteq E$.
            $$f(U) = \{f(x) \colon x \in U\}$$

As $x \in U$, $\exists \alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n \in \mathbb K$ such that
            $$x = \alpha_1 u_1 + \cdots + \alpha_n u_n$$
Consequently, as $f$ is a linear application,
            $$f(U) = \{ \alpha_1 f(u_1) + \cdots + \alpha_n f(u_n) \colon \alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n \in \mathbb K \}$$

We know that $f(x) \in F$, so $f(U) \subseteq F$. Let's see if it is a vector subspace.

- > $f(U) \neq \varnothing$.

  True, because setting $\alpha_1 = \cdots = \alpha_n = 0$ yields $0_F \in f(U)$.
- > $\forall a, b \in f(U) \implies (a+b) \in f(U)$.

  Let $a, b \in f(U) \implies \exists\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n, \beta_1, \dots, \beta_n \in \mathbb K$ such that
              $$a = \alpha_1 f(u_1) + \cdots + \alpha_n f(u_n) \qquad \text{and}\qquad b = \beta_1 f(u_1) + \cdots + \beta_n f(u_n)$$
  Consequently, $a + b = (\alpha_1 + \beta_1) f(u_1) + \cdots + (\alpha_n + \beta_n) f(u_n) \in f(U)$.
- > $\forall a \in f(U)$ and $\forall \lambda \in \mathbb K \implies \lambda a \in f(U)$.

  $$\lambda a = \lambda\big(\alpha_1 f(u_1) + \cdots + \alpha_n f(u_n)\big) = (\lambda \alpha_1) f(u_1) + \cdots + (\lambda \alpha_n) f(u_n) \in f(U)$$

So $f(U) \subseteq F$ is a vector subspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be a little bit more careful. Certainly $f(0_E)=0_F$ (this is easily deduced from linearity of $f$). I would usually spell out the arguments a little, to make it absolutely obvious. The argument you present relies on the statement that $$f(U)=\{\alpha_1f(u_1)+\dots+\alpha_nf(u_n):u_1,\dots,u_n\in U,\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n\in\mathbb{K}\}$$ which is presented without justification.

For sums and scalar products, you need to take an element of $F$ and find an element of $E$ which is mapped to that element. For example, take $x\in f(U)$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb{K}$. We need to show that $\alpha x\in f(U)$. To do this, find $w\in U$ with $f(w)=x$. Since $f$ is linear $\alpha x=\alpha f(w)=f(\alpha w)$, and so $\alpha x$ is the image of an element in $U$ (since $U$ is a vector subspace). Argue similarly for sums.